# Create a Grid View in android with unequal widths of items in the rows

Tags: android, gridview, android-recyclerview, gridlayoutmanager

I am trying to create a layout emulating the image below.

UI of desired screen:
[image]

I have two xml files which I need to call in a list. Their properties and number of rows in list are dynamic so are populated during run time. Their heights are the same. However their widths must me distributed across the screen in the ratio 1:1:1.3.

I tried first using gridview, next I tried recyclerview using gridlayoutmanager. I can set the widths statically in the onBindViewHolder() of adapter. But it comes different for different screens and also affects the spacing between items which I have set using RecyclerView.ItemDecoration. Is there any way to set widths of items dynamically w.r t other items in the row ?

Here are parts of my code:

In onCreate() of Activity:

```
recyclerViewLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(context,3);
int spacingInPixels =    getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen._3sdp);
recyclerView.addItemDecoration(new StoreSpaces(spacingInPixels));
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(recyclerViewLayoutManager);
recyclerView.setAdapter(new StoreRecycleAdapter(context,backgroundTheme, categoryNames));
```

Adapter Class:

```
public class StoreRecycleAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {

Context context;
int[] contentBg ;
final int CATEGORY =0, SUBCATEGORY=1;
String[] catNames;

StoreRecycleAdapter (Context context, int[] contentBg, String[] catNames){
    this.contentBg =contentBg;
    this.context   =context;
    this.catNames  =catNames 

}

@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder;
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());

    switch (viewType) {
        case CATEGORY:
            View v1 = inflater.inflate(R.layout.category,parent, false);
            viewHolder = new ViewHolder1(v1);
            break;
        case SUBCATEGORY:
            View v2 = inflater.inflate(R.layout.subcategory, parent, false);
            viewHolder = new ViewHolder1(v2);
            break;
        default:
            View v3 = inflater.inflate(android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, parent, false);
            viewHolder = new ViewHolder1(v3);
            break;
    }

    return viewHolder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {

    switch (holder.getItemViewType()) {
        case CATEGORY:

            break;
        case SUBCATEGORY:
           /* ViewGroup.LayoutParams params2 = holder.itemView.getLayoutParams();
            params2.width =270;
            holder.itemView.setLayoutParams(params2);*/
            ViewHolder1 vh1 = (ViewHolder1) holder;
            vh1.gridText.setText(catNames[position]);
            vh1.gridLL.setBackgroundResource(contentBg[position]);
            break;
        default:

            break;
    }


}


@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    if ((position-2)%3==0 ) {
        return CATEGORY;
    } else
        return SUBCATEGORY;


}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return catNames.length ;
}

public class ViewHolder1 extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    RelativeLayout gridLL;
    TextView gridText;
    public ViewHolder1(View v){
        super(v);
        gridLL = (RelativeLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.gridLayout);
        gridText = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.nameTxt);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Provide some of you relevant code-trails from which we can take reference from.